# Why does terminal not accept folder when there is space in folder name?

Tags: powershell, project

While adding the project to GitHub ,I created the folder name " gokce game". When I tried to copy the path to m file and navigate to it, I got an error indicating that I cloud not navigate to this file. I couldn't understand what the problem was and my job was incomplete.

Error Code :

- cd gokce game
- Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ' oyun'.
  At line:1 char:1
  CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
  FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKmVk.png)

Answer (score 1):

When there are spaces in the path, it must be quoted. That is, `cd "gokce game"` or `cd 'gokce game'`.

The reason is that command parsing cannot tell if `gokce` and `game` are two different things or just a single thing. By enclosing the directory name within quote characters, it is evident that there is a single string, not two space separated strings.

The error message can a bit tricky to understand, so let's look at it with more details. In Powershell, `cd` is actually an alias to cmdlet `Set-Location`. That cmdlet expects to have a single string argument - the directory in which one wants to change the current directory to. (It also supports locations such as registry paths, but that's another a story.) Now when the cmdlet sees two string paramters, `gokce` and `game`, it doesn't understand what the second one is about.

Powershell's usually smart enough to handle multiple parameters if those are passed in right order and the receiving cmdlet supports that. A typical example is `Copy-Item` which will copy the thing specified in parameter1 into parameter2. In the `cd` situation, there is no expectation to get 2nd parameter, thus the error.

Further info is available at [about quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2) and [Set-Location aka cd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-7.2).